# Were the Knights of Zakuul in SW:TOR inspired by the Imperial Knights in the novels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

In the later expansions of *Star Wars: The Old Republic*, you find your way onto a previously unknown empire that has a sort of police force that are Force users that are neither Jedi nor Sith. They are armored, wield lightsabers, use the Force as a tool for battle, and don't really fall towards the light or dark side.

[Imperial Knights](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Knight) are part of a later Galactic Empire (post Battle of Endor), and follow a similar thing, even going as far as killing any of their own who fall to the dark side (including their emperor).

Has there been any source from BioWare or anyone else saying that the concept of the Knights of Zakuul came from the EU books?